# Application is appearing upside down inside the HoloLens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens, mrtk, hololens-emulator

We have developed Unity application (Version: 2018.4.21f1) - MRTK UWP Project. Which we basically develop and planned to deploy into HoloLens 2 device. But as of of now we do not have the device and currently testing it through HoloLens 2 emulator. When we test the application inside Unity, everything works fine but when we build the project and deploy it into HL2 emulator from Visual Studio 2019, the whole application is upside down inside the emulator. If anyone have faced this issue in the past or want me to share any inspector settings? please let me know.

Thanks in advance.
Srikanth

Comment: We have not seen this issue before. Could you provide any screenshot about this issue? As a test, could you create a simple unity project and build and run it on the latest version HoloLens emulator(Download from here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2126826)? Do you see the same behavior? This will help narrow down if it's an issue with emulator or an issue with Unity.

Comment: Have you updated the rendering pipeline to Unity's new universal render pipeline? There is a bug about a flipped upside/down view on a HMD. While I've only encountered it during deployment it might related to your issue. https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/vr-hmd-view-is-flipped-upside-down-when-lwrp-is-enabled